# HTTP Status 400 in Spring and Hibernate app

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and Hibernate for making a registration page. when I enter the details in the registration page and then click on submit, it is giving me Http 400:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: too few details

Answer (score 0):

Are you validating input at controller level using @Valid ?

If not u have probably mismatch between request content and model